# Parse LESS variables into PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing, less

Could you help me please:

I have a LESS file with variables, e.g.

```
/** preloader colors **/
@preloader_bg: #0081ff;
@preloader_color: #fff;

/** layout **/
@body_bg_image_position: ~'left top';
@body_bg_image_repeat: ~'no-repeat';
@body_bg_image_cover: ~'auto';
@body_bg_image: ~'';
```

I need to parse this file into PHP and get an array like this:

```
$less_vars = array(
  'preloader_bg' => '#0081ff',
  'body_bg_image_position' => 'left top'
);
```

Can this be done with regular expressions or in any another way?

Comment: Switch over to SASS as there is a great SASS parser available for PHP. Also, since LESS and SASS are languages that should only be parsed, don't work backwards..

Comment: thank you, but the current problem in LESS not SASS

Comment: You should state what you've tried so far so that others know you've done some research or tried something. Otherwise, you're unlikely to get an answer. See StackOverflow help center [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Sherif no problem if anybody can't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can go with one single RegEx:

```
^@([^:]+):[~\s]*(['\"]?)([^;]*)\\2;?$
```

PHP ([Live demo](https://3v4l.org/LHvpm)):

```
preg_match_all("/^@([^:]+):[~\s]*(['\"]?)([^;]*)\\2;?$/m", $str, $matches);
var_dump(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[3]));
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  ["preloader_bg"]=>
  string(7) "#0081ff"
  ["preloader_color"]=>
  string(4) "#fff"
  ["body_bg_image_position"]=>
  string(8) "left top"
  ["body_bg_image_repeat"]=>
  string(9) "no-repeat"
  ["body_bg_image_cover"]=>
  string(4) "auto"
  ["body_bg_image"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: You are Pro! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the input line by line, then split the lines at the `:`. This should, after some cleaning up, give you the keys and their values.

[See the ideone](http://ideone.com/5qer81)

```
$input = "
/** preloader colors **/
@preloader_bg: #0081ff;
@preloader_color: #fff;

/** layout **/
@body_bg_image_position: ~'left top';
@body_bg_image_repeat: ~'no-repeat';
@body_bg_image_cover: ~'auto';
@body_bg_image: ~'';
";

// create an array to store the values
$cssVar = [];

// iterate over the lines
foreach (split("\n", $input) as $ln) {
    // ignore lines that don't start with @ as they are not variables
    if ($ln[0] != "@") {
        continue;
    }
    // get the key and value for the css variable
    // TODO: cleanup ~ mark
    $bits = explode(":", $ln);
    $key = substr(trim($bits[0]), 1);
    $value = trim($bits[1]);

    // store the value
    $cssVar[$key] = $value;
}

var_export($cssVar);
```

Comment: that's what i thought about right now, thank you so much!